# socketserver change port in runtime?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, socketserver

Is it possible to change the port (in this case change from "1111") after everything has been set up on the server side?

```
import socketserver

class ServerHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            self.request.sendall(b"test") # Send data to the client(s)

server = socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(("localhost", 1111), ServerHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Change the port and restart the server?

Comment: I assume you mean create a new socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer and assign it to the same variable? If so, my only concern is the clients (which are not written by me) may try to connect the server between this extremely short period while the old server doesn't exist but the new one hasn't been created yet either. I think this is low probability to happen but is possible. But if you meant something else let me know or post it as an answer.

Comment: Correct, you must close down the old server socket and startup a new server socket.  Whether you create the new server first, or shutdown the old server first, shouldn't really matter. If a client happens to connect to the old server, it is just going to get disconnected anyway.